# Can we say the primal problem get $+\infty/-\infty$ if the dual problem is infeasible?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, operations-research

It can be easily verified that if the optimal value of the primal problem is $+\infty/-\infty$, the dual problem is infeasible. How about the inverse? If the dual problem is infeasible, can we say that the optimal value of the primal problem is $+\infty/-\infty$ if the primal problem is feasible?

Comment: If the primal is feasible, yes. However, if the dual is infeasible the primal can be infeasible or feasible. If it is feasible, however, then the optimal value will be $\pm \infty$. Yet, it might just as well be infeasible.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for both the primal and dual problems to be infeasible.  An example from Vasek Chvatal's LP textbook is:

$\max \;\; 2x_{1}-x_{2}$

$ x_{1}-x_{2} \leq 1$

$-x_{1} +x_{2} \leq -2$

$x_{1}, x_{2} \geq 0$.

Comment: Yes, but what if the primal problem is feasible?

Comment: In LP, if the dual problem is infeasible and the primal problem is feasible, then it must be that the primal problem is unbounded.